# как правильно сформировать sql запрос

Tags: sql, база-данных, firebird

Написать запрос, позволяющий заполнить поле abc таблицы TABLE_X случайными значениями, находящимися между наименьшим и наибольшим значениями поля abc таблицы TABLE_Y.
Какая нужна конструкция ?
По отдельности знаю как сделать, а чтобы все вместе работало - нет
субд firebird 2.5

[image: TABLE_A]

[image: TABLE_B]

Получается min = 1 max = 74, надо в этом диапазоне заполнить таблицу B случайными числами

Comment: приведите пример исходных данных и желаемый результат

Comment: Привел в описании

Comment: update TABLE_X 
   set abc = (select trunc(Rand() * Max(abc) + Min(abc)) from TABLE_Y)